# Formatting property for display

Tags: c#, formatting

I am storing item's price in database as `int`. Now, I want to display that data in my a app s it were double. I found 2 ways to do this:

```
class Item
{
    public int Cost { get; private set; }
    public string CostFormatted { get { return ((double)Cost/100).ToString(); } }
}
```

and second:

```
class Item
{
    private int cost;

    public int Cost {
        get { return cost; }

        set {
            cost = value;
            CostFormatted = ((double)cost / 100).ToString();
        }
    }
    public string CostFormatted { get; private set; }
}
```

which one is better to use?

Comment: What kind of app is this? Could you be more specific about that?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. [Questions should include a description of what the code does](//codereview.meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226)

Answer (score 2):

IMPORTANT NOTE: consider this a *general* answer. The specific UI framework you're using leads to what's the *best practice* to use. If, for example, this is a WPF application then you just need a plain `ValueConverter` and no properties in your View Model (again...assuming this is your VM).

---

First of all casting to `double` you're introducing errors, the same errors you're trying to avoid storing pennies in an `int` field. Use `decimal` instead (and consider to use `Money` - or whatever else your DBE has - inside the database).

I, personally, find extremely confusing to have a property `Cost` expressed in pennies. You may change the name to make it explicit (something like `CostInPennies`) or drop it and convert it to/from `decimal` when you read/write to/from DB (and the *unadjusted* value).

What's better between alternatives you've proposed? What's the benefit of the first? It's small and it keeps the logic *in the right place*. I'd rewrite it to be more concise:

```
public string DisplayCost => Convert.ToString(Cost / 100.0m);
```

The second one, however, has a great benefit if your object is observable: updating the `DisplayCost` property keeps the `INotifyPropertyChanged` stuff inside the `DisplayCost` setter leading to much cleaner code. If you don't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (or similar) then I'd go with the first one (and I'd not even bother to store the value somewhere, just recalculate it when required).

In any case I'd introduce a simple helper method to perform this formatting (there are good chances it's reused elsewhere), something like:

```
static class MoneyFormatter {
    public static string PenniesToString(int pennies)
        => Convert.ToString(pennies / 100.0m);
}
```

You can then test its logic without any `Item`'s implementation detail. In future you may need to handle something else and it's then better to have everything in one place. Don't forget:

- Thousands separator: it is probably helpful to quickly scan a column of numbers.
- Rounding: you don't always need precision to one penny, in some circumstances (for example a dashboard) you MAY even round (for example 10,123$ might be displayed as 10k).
- Currency symbol: if you display amounts using different currencies then you may need to add it.
- Negative values: for money it's not uncommon to display negative values with a formatting that it's not the same one used for *plain* numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is a wrong approach (I also don't agree with the other answer's helper). The view/UI should be formatting the output. Most components support formatting for strings.

In your case the property should be just a raw value like

```
public string CostInPercent => Cost / 100.0; // or any other name that makes sense
```

that the view now formats whatever it likes. Maybe even by adding `%` symbol to it.

Comment: I agree but it really depends which technology he's using for his UI. Assuming this is his VM and not his business logic (!!!) then it might be a dumb WPF control (dumb otherwise a `ValueConverter` is more appropriate), some simple WinForms control, a raw `PropertyGrid` or the _view model_ returned to a very simple HTML page which blindly display some tabular data. Anyway, my upv, if possible this should be an UI task.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti _I am storing item's price in database_ - I don't think it's OP's view-model. But even if it was then still, I can't think of any ui-component that wouldn't be able to format output the way you like.

Comment: Because you're lucky and you wiped WinForms from your memory! That `/100` makes me think he is storing pennies (1/100) instead of decimal values. If he has pennies then he need a property with _whole_ values and not every WinForms control supports databinding (assuming `/100` is calculated in the model). Even controls with the required support (which may be a simple format string) can't often perform more sophisticated things (like _dynamic_ rounding to k$, for example)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti haha, no I didn't ;-) I spent a lot of time with win-forms and (however most of it with dev-express) but let's not argue... who knows what OP is really doing. This question actually extremely lacks context so I'm wondering why I didn't vote to close it... here is anything possible. Ok, now I did VTC, but I should have done it earlier.

Comment: you're right, actually I answered without any context...it was really better to ask or close (I'm thinking that if that's for a WPF app then I gave a TERRIBLE suggestion)

Answer (score 1):

I like the first but I would expose decimal also. In the second if you assign `cost` directly then the `CostFormatted =` is missed. N2 for two decimal places.

```
public class Item
{
    public int Cost { get; private set; }
    public decimal CostDecimal { get { return Cost / 100m; } }
    public string CostFormated { get { return string.Format(CostDecimal.ToString("N2")); } }  
    public Item (int cost)
    {
        Cost = cost;
    }
}
```

And I would call `Cost` `CostInt`.

Comment: I agree! I'd even leave there ONLY the property with `decimal` type.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I get leaving the int as integer math is faster.